# The featured stackoverflow blog posts have the stackexchange logo

Tags: bug, blog, tooltips, sidebar, logo

See picture:

[image: cropped screenshot of the right hand panel which shows blogs and featured meta posts. The Tooltip over the logo for the stackoverflow blog reads "Meta Stack Exchange"]

The icon/logo and tooltip are confusing at first glance.

Comment: Those are normally blog-posts on https://stackoverflow.blog/ - but you are right - it's a little confusing to have the SE-logo besides them.. When you visit those links linked to SO-blog, then the favicon in the tabs show the SO-logo again - hmmmm...